# Gradient in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, gradient, fxml

How do I develop a gradient in JavaFX that looks like the one below?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html

Answer (score 8):

Use `linear-gradient` in `CSS`:

`linear-gradient(to` (top, right, bottom, left)`,` (color begin)`,` (color finish)`);`

```
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top,-color-amber, transparent);
```