# how to change fill color of slider in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

im making a video player and want to use a slider for timeline and i want to change slider from first picture to second

[image]

[image]

can i just use css code to do this ? if yes what is the code for this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Long post below.. if you want an easy way to achieve the color on your slider I should mention that you can just use the [JFoenix Slider](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/wiki/Slider) which has the functionalities you need**.

Although there is actually no need to use a 3rd library if you can achieve the same result natively.

Well, there isn't any CSS rule like `-fx-progress-color` which you set to a specific color and then you are done. The color of the .track  is set with the CSS rule below :

```
.slider .track {
      -fx-background-color:
          -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          linear-gradient(to bottom,
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 0%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -5%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -12%)
          );
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.25em, 0.25em, 0.166667em; /* 3 3 2 */
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3 */
}
```

There are few things you need to do, the first one is to listen for value changes of your slider and second to update your track color depending on the slider's value. To set the background color you will need to set a linear-gradient to the background like  :

`-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D START, #969696 END);`

With the code above, you will set a linear gradient background starting from the left to right using the color #2D819D which is the 'progress' color and the #969696 which represents the remaining progress. Now the START and the END should be numbers and in order to have the look you want, both numbers must be equal so when the one stops the other starts. For example if you set :

`-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D 20%, #969696 20%);`

[image]

The real challenge is to find a way to set these values programmatically inside the ChangeListener of your slider. My first approach was to use a CSS variable like :

```
.slider .track{
    -progress : 0.2;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D -progress, #969696 -progress);
}
```

And to update the `-progress` using inline CSS rules on ChangeListener. Sadly for some reason this is not supported. I would love to find out why too. Also, you can't apply inline CSS for the subclass, which means you can not do slider.setStyle(".track {...}");

So to summarize, you could either :

**1. Access the slider's track using lookup and apply the CSS directly.**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomSlider extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(15));

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setId("color-slider");

        mainPane.setCenter(slider);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 250, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        StackPane trackPane = (StackPane) slider.lookup(".track");

        slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                String style = String.format("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D %d%%, #969696 %d%%);",
                        new_val.intValue(), new_val.intValue());
                trackPane.setStyle(style);
            }
        });

        trackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D 0%, #969696 0%);");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**2. Make a custom Slider from scratch (not that hard)**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(15));

        mainPane.setCenter(new ColorSlider());

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 250, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public class ColorSlider extends StackPane {

        public ColorSlider() {
            getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("colorSlider.css").toExternalForm());
            Slider slider = new Slider();
            slider.setId("color-slider");

            // The rectangle which shows the progress
            Rectangle progressRec = new Rectangle();
            // Bind both width and height to match the size of Slider
            progressRec.heightProperty().bind(slider.heightProperty().subtract(7));
            progressRec.widthProperty().bind(slider.widthProperty());

            progressRec.setFill(Color.web("#969696"));

            // Make the corners of Rectangle to be rounded
            progressRec.setArcHeight(15);
            progressRec.setArcWidth(15);

            // Listen on value changes on the slider to update the progress (color)
            slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                    // Using linear gradient we can fill two colors to show the progress
                    // the new_val gets values between 0 - 100
                    String style = String.format("-fx-fill: linear-gradient(to right, #2D819D %d%%, #969696 %d%%);",
                            new_val.intValue(), new_val.intValue());
                    // set the Style
                    progressRec.setStyle(style);
                }
            });

            getChildren().addAll(progressRec, slider);
        }
    }
}
```

colorSlider.css

```
#color-slider .track{
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a `JFXSlider` and I'm trying to access the track node, but the first solution (the one with `.lookup()`) isn't working.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy may I ask why you want to access the track node of JFXSlider? I might be able to help you or to give you a suggestion.

Comment: I would like to have a linear gradient from red to orange (or maybe some other color; I'm still finding the exact color I need) for the track node of the `JFXSlider`. Thanks!

Comment: I've been able to partially solve the problem [using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44677209/14270627). However, I still have to get rid of the `JFXSlider`'s own green color. I think using a color of `transparent` for that would work, but I don't know where I can change its own color. Thanks!

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy  It is very easy to implement it ( just did ) you could find all the CSS rules here https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/wiki/Slider . In case you don't know how to use the css rules in the link, I could provide you with a small example if you create a new post, let me know and i will post a full example there.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I understand how to use the CSS rules in the link. However, I would also like to have the slider's thumb have the same color as that of the slider at the position of the thumb on the slider. P.S. If you believe that this comment would be better suited as a question, I'll ask a new question about this. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, now I see what you want to accomplish. I do believe this would be a good question to ask as a new post. I will give it a try to implement it and post an answer if you decided to make a new post ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385864) about it.

Comment: There's no need to hack this with a lookup. JAvaFX CSS supports "looked-up colors", which are essentially CSS variables (but unfortunately they are only supported for `Paint` types, not for other types). So you can do this in the CSS file: `.slider { -track-color: /* default value */;} .slider .track { -fx-background-color: -track-color;}` and then in the Java code (i.e. in the slider's change listener) update the color: `slider.setStyle("-track-color: /* computed gradient */;");`.

Comment: I added an answer demonstrating the idea in my previous comment.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a slight variation on [@JKostikiadis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167500/jkostikiadis)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344773/2189127) which avoids the CSS lookup. CSS lookups can be problematic, because they will return `null` unless CSS has been applied and a layout pass has been made. The referenced answer avoids this by looking up the track *after* showing the stage, but this can be hard to achieve in some circumstances (particularly using FXML, where controller initialization necessarily happens before the UI is added to a scene). This answer also goes to some lengths to preserve the default style as much as is reasonably possible.

The basic strategy here is to:

- use "looked up colors" to define the linear gradient which separates the track to the left of the value from the track to the right of the value
- set the background color of the track based on the looked-up colors
- use `setStyle(...)` on the slider to modify the looked-up color programmatically.

This avoids the CSS lookup, because looked-up colors are inherited in CSS. Thus it's enough to modify the looked-up color only on the slider itself: the track (to which you don't readily have a reference) will inherit the value.

It's worth looking at the default CSS applied to the slider and its track, which you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L957):

```
.slider .track {
      -fx-background-color:
          -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          linear-gradient(to bottom,
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 0%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -5%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -12%)
          );
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.25em, 0.25em, 0.166667em; /* 3 3 2 */
    -fx-padding: 0.25em; /* 3 */
}
```

This background is a "nested background" with the nesting defined by the three background inset values. The first value for `-fx-background-color` defines a shadow 1 pixel below the track; the second (given by the first linear gradient) defines a 1-pixel border with a subtle gradient, and the third (the second linear gradient) defines the majority of the track: it is a subtle linear gradient based on the standard theme color `-fx-control-inner-background`.

The plan here is to retain the border and the shadow, and vary the piece in the middle using a linear gradient. Since we can't use a linear gradient as the target of another linear gradient, we will approximate the default center of the track with `-fx-control-inner-background`:

```
.slider {
    -default-track-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -track-color: -default-track-color ;
}
```

and then use the same construct to wrap the shadow and border around the track color. Note we can just use the default insets and padding defined in the default stylesheet: there is no need to redefine them here:

```
.slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          -track-color;
}
```

Now in the Java code we can just update the `-track-color` defined by the slider:

```
    slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        double percentage = 100.0 * newValue.doubleValue() / slider.getMax();
        String style = String.format(
                // in the String format, 
                // %1$.1f%% gives the first format argument ("1$"),
                // i.e. percentage, formatted to 1 decimal place (".1f").
                // Note literal % signs must be escaped ("%%")
                "-track-color: linear-gradient(to right, " +
                        "-fx-accent 0%%, " +
                        "-fx-accent %1$.1f%%, " +
                        "-default-track-color %1$.1f%%, " +
                        "-default-track-color 100%%);",
                percentage);
        slider.setStyle(style);
    });
```

Here's a complete example:

style.css:

```
.slider {
    -default-track-color: -fx-control-inner-background;
    -track-color: -default-track-color ;
}

.slider .track {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          -track-color;
}
```

and

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProgressSlider extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            double percentage = 100.0 * newValue.doubleValue() / slider.getMax();
            String style = String.format(
                    "-track-color: linear-gradient(to right, " +
                            "-fx-accent 0%%, " +
                            "-fx-accent %1$.1f%%, " +
                            "-default-track-color %1$.1f%%, " +
                            "-default-track-color 100%%);",
                    percentage);
            slider.setStyle(style);
        });
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(slider);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]