# How to change color of slider thumb in JavaFx CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, slider

So, I would like to change the size, fill color, and border thickness of the thumb/handle on the slider.  I can't seem to find the property to change.  I've checked all documentation I can find.  I'm sure this is a simple fix.  Below is my most promising attempt. Any ideas?

```
#comfortSlider {

    -fx-control-inner-background: #1354cb; 
    /* This works in changing the track */

}

#comfortSlider:thumb {

    -fx-background-color: #1354cb;
    /* This doesn't work in changing the thumb */

}
```

To clarify, this is what I mean by thumb.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try !important to override the original style.

```
#comfortSlider{-fx-control-inner-background: #1354cb!important;}

#comfortSlider:thumb{-fx-background-color: #1354cb!important;}
```

Comment: Ah, that's probably useful to have in there.  It still didn't work, but I think I'm not actually sure if the :thumb extension is real.  Do you know?

Comment: Not sure but I will do a little research for you.

Comment: Did you design this slider or are you using a framework or plugin for it?

Comment: Did you design it from a range?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343759/how-to-change-fill-color-of-slider-in-javafx          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304300/implementing-css-on-javafx-slider       Try these links it may help

Comment: Amazing, thank you, sorry for the slow response.  I will accept your answer and describe the final solution below.

Comment: can't get this to work as setStyle(":thumb{-fx-background-color: #1354cb!important;}") or variations on that. I want a distinct thumb color when the thumb is at min or max.

Answer (score 3):

So, what I did was change the line

```
#comfortSlider:thumb {
```

to

```
#comfortSlider .thumb {
```

The space between `comfortSlider` and `.thumb` is necessary.  `!important` was not necessary in my case, but if you need to override other styles, then I imagine it would be.  Thank you to @Jonny for the help.