# How can I change the color of a JFXSlider's thumb according to the color of the slider at the current position of the thumb on the slider?

Tags: java, css, javafx, jfoenix, javafx-css

I'm using a `JFXSlider` in JavaFX and I've used a linear gradient for the color of the `JFXSlider`'s track (with CSS). However, I'd also like to change the color of the thumb to that of the slider for that position. I've used the following CSS for the slider's linear gradient and for getting rid of the default green color of the `JFXSlider`:

```css
.jfx-slider .track {
    -fx-pref-height: 10;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right,red,orange);
}
.jfx-slider .colored-track {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

I tried the following CSS code to get the thumb color to be the same as that of the slider at the current position, but it didn't work.

```css
.jfx-slider .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right,red,orange);
}
```

I guess it's probably that the code I tried only provides an *internal* linear gradient for the thumb's background color. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? P.S. I'm using JFoenix 9.0.10, JavaFX 15, and JDK 15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution would be to add a global CSS variable and change it depending on the JFXSlider current value. For example :

```
.root {
    -fx-custom-color : red;
}
```

And then use this variable on your jfx-slider css rules like :

```
/* Styling the slider thumb */
.jfx-slider>.thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-custom-color;
}

/* Styling the animated thumb */
.jfx-slider>.animated-thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-custom-color;
}
```

After that, you need to figure out how to update the "-fx-custom-color" variable and how to determine which color you need to set for the specific value of the Slider (or rather location).

First, you should add a listener to the value property to listen for value changes. Second, use the interpolate method of the Color class to determine the color, and finally, update the new value for the `-fx-custom-color` using inline CSS style to the JFXSlider.

Here is a complete example :

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSlider;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderTesting extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        JFXSlider slider = new JFXSlider(0, 100, 0);

        slider.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
            Color imageColor = Color.RED.interpolate(Color.ORANGE,
                    slider.getValue() / 100);
            slider.setStyle("-fx-custom-color : " + colorToHex(imageColor) + ";");
        });

        VBox box = new VBox(slider);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        box.setPrefSize(400, 400);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        scene.getStylesheets()
                .add(this.getClass().getResource("custom-jfoenix.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static String colorToHex(Color color) {
        return String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", (int) (color.getRed() * 255),
                (int) (color.getGreen() * 255), (int) (color.getBlue() * 255));
    }
}
```

And the "custom-jfoenix.css" file

```
.root {
    -fx-custom-color : red;
}

/* Styling the slider track */
.jfx-slider>.track {
    -fx-pref-height: 10;
}

/* Styling the slider thumb */
.jfx-slider>.thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-custom-color;
}

/* Styling the filled track */
.jfx-slider>.colored-track {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, red, orange);
}

/* Styling the animated thumb */
.jfx-slider>.animated-thumb {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-custom-color;
}
```

And the result :

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. I used `slider1.valueProperty().addListener((ov,old,nw)->slider1.setStyle("-fx-custom-color:"+colorToHex(Color.RED.interpolate(Color.ORANGE,nw.doubleValue()/100))));` (sorry for the compacted code; I like to have compacted code). Basically, I just used a `ChangeListener` instead of an `InvalidationListener`. Any help here? Thanks!

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy Interesting, your code works fine for me. Please update your main post with the JFoenix version and Java version you are using.

Comment: Although your answer still isn't working for me, I've decided to upvote it.

Comment: I just installed OpenJDK 15.0.1, JavaFX SDK 15.0.1 and JFoenix 9.0.10 and everything works fine. When you say that the above code isn't working what do you mean? Could you please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Oh, I just realized what's going on. Your slider has a range of 0 to 100, while my slider has a range of 1 to 10, so I should probably use something like `(nw.doubleValue()-1)/9` or whatever. Thanks for all of the help! I've just accepted your answer.

Comment: P.S. Because I used 100, the color that came out of the `Color.RED.interpolate()` method was very close to red, and I thought that the color wasn't changing. Now it's working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226241/discussion-between-the-tech-expert-guy-and-jkostikiadis).